# Check if Favicon is set in Customizer

Tags: php, theme-customizer, favicon

There's this "Site Icon" option in the customizer, which allows you to set a favicon. I'm creating a theme which already has its own favicon.

How can I check if the favicon is already set in the customizer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress saves the Favicon as `site_icon` in the options table holding the attachment post ID. What you could do is something like this:

```
if( false === get_option( 'site_icon', false ) ) {
    // Show favicon
}
```

Where [`get_option()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_option/) will hit the default ( we provide as the 2nd parameter ) `false` IF the `site_icon` does not exist or one has not been uploaded through the customizer.